# Spark join pushed to Mongo ?

Tags: mongodb, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am processing data from Mongo and would like to know if the joins in Spark are pushed to MongoDB.
I understood that MongoDB (>=3.2) has a $lookup operator to do left outer join between 2 collections.

But what if I want to do the join in Spark using Spark SQL. Would it load the 2 collections entirely in Spark first and then do the join or would the join be 'converted' to a $lookup query in MongoDB ?

Thanks,

Comment: It will depends how the code is written .

Comment: Currently, I'm unaware of any mechanism in Spark that could push the fact there was a join down to MongoDB.